# Getting 'tensor is not a torch image' for data type <class 'torch.Tensor'>

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, tensor

As the question suggests, I'm trying to convert `images` to tensor.

```
X, y = train_sequence[idx]  

images = Variable(torch.from_numpy(X)).to(device) # [batch, channel, H, W]
masks = Variable(torch.from_numpy(y)).to(device) 
print(type(images)) ## Output: <class 'torch.Tensor'>


images = transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5,0.5, 0.5))(images)
masks =  transforms.Normalize((0.5), (0.5))(masks)
```

But I get the error at
 `---> 19         images = transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5,0.5, 0.5))(images)`

`TypeError: tensor is not a torch image.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because as of now, `torchvison.transforms.Normalize` only supports images with 2 or 3 channels, without the batch dimension, ie. `(C, H, W)`. So instead of passing in a 4D tensor, something like this would work:

```
image = torch.ones(3, 64, 64)
image = transforms.Noramalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))(image)
```

Also, because the `0.5` values represent the mean and standard deviation of the image channels, there should normally only be 3 channels (you don't "normalise" the batch dimension, only the spatial ones), so instead of using a `tuple` of length 5, do `(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)`.